# Synchronized set in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there a synchronized set class in Python? Like [`Queue.Queue`](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html)? I'm sending messages to a JMS queue and need to handle reciepts:

- Keep track of sent messages in a set
- When a receipt is received, removed it from the set
- When the set is empty, set an Event

Something with the same interface as `Queue` would be perfect, but I need to be able to remove things in any order.

Comment: Set operations are atomic (because of the GIL). There is no atomic "check if set is empty and set event" however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for object Locking.
http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

Basicly, you lock the thread's execution based on an object. When you're done with the object, you release it and the thread continues.

Answer (score 2):

Well [Queue.Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) use a [deque](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) under the hood ([and deque is not thread safe](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2004-July/046350.html)).

So what you can do is extend the Queue.Queue class and add a new method and in it you can call the deque method [deque.remove()](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque.remove) (if this is what you mean by removing elements in any order), and make sure that your new method is thread safe look at the [Queue.Queue.put()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/a85cf047f56a/Lib/queue.py#l124) method to see an example of what you should do.

Well it's a bit risky and race condition problems are very hard to debug if you miss something, but hope this can give a clear view.